# when re-opening the activity how to show user background service status

Tags: android, android-service

i am using a service call in activity button on click method

the activity and service is running correctly
when the start button is clicked the message displayed that activity is started,
and now user can switch to other activity.

but when user again open the same actvity ,then how to show the service status ,that the service is running correctly in background.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Get information about service status, or how to show it in the interface?

Comment: basic need is to get the service stautus>>either it is running or not>>

Comment: but  second case is also appreciated if you know how to solve it>>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simpler way is to have a static boolean variable in your Service that indicates its current state. You could set it to true when the service starts running and set to false when it's stopped and retrieve it from your activity to show the user the proper message.

However, if you don't like this approach you can also tell us how are you starting the service and when it should be stopped/started to see other solutions.

Comment: after re-switching the activity the variable is destroyed> its again start from initials point.oncreate method

Comment: The variable should be false by default, so if it is destroyed, that means that would be false and that your service is no longer running.

Comment: actually service is running in background and user can switch to other activity> when user re open the activity the service is running in background but value is false.

Comment: If the value is false that means that you're not setting to true in the correct method. Check how are you starting the service (via binder or startService method).

Comment: i am using start service >>

Comment: According to the Services lifecycle documentation  (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) you should set that variable to **true in the onStartCommand** method of your Service, and set it back to **false in the onDestroy**.

Comment: where do i declare the bool var> in service or in main activity> because if i set it main activity it can't be accessble in service onstart method.

Comment: You should create it in the Service (public static boolean isRunning ...) and access it from the Activity (MyService.isRunning) when you want to show it to the user.

Comment: thanks a lot its working for me>and also thanks for comments replies>